# ctrl-x o backwards (opposite of other-window)?

Tags: emacs

> CTRL-x o - switch cursor to other window

I would like to have the ability to reverse what `control-x o` does. Something like `control-x p` that does exactly what `control-x o` does, but backwards. The reason for this request is that I often have two buffers open that are code and one buffer open that is a repl. I often have to move across one of the buffers to get to the other, that is annoying.

Say I have 3 buffers open (A, B, C), and I am on buffer B. The buffers are in alphabetical order in terms of `control-x o`. When I want to go to A, I want to just press `control-x p`, rather than having to press `control-x o` twice.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `other-window` with a negative count.  This can be done interactively by pressing  <kbd>C--</kbd> <kbd>C-x o</kbd>.  The "C--" is supplying a numeric argument of -1.  You can supply any numeric (NUM) by pressing <kbd>C-u num</kbd>.

If you don't want to press the additional key cord, just write you own command command to hard code the "-1" argument:

Add this code to your `.emacs` file

```
(global-set-key "\C-xp" (lambda () 
                          (interactive)
                          (other-window -1)))
```

How does it work? "C-x o" calls the function `other-window` (to find that out use `C-h k` and then type the key combo).

In the code above we define an anonymous function, make it interactive and do what we want. Then we bind that function to the key combinaion `C-x p`.

Comment: Cool beans, lightly tested, seems to work. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You can also just use the `C--` prefix to `C-x o`.  This is the equivalent of a `-1` numeric argument.  Any other numric arguments will also work to skip ahead or behind.

Comment: @event_jr Yes, an explanation of prefix arguments would certainly be in order. Feel free to edit it into my post.

Answer (score 0):

I was using emacs for a bit and i dont renember having any backward option of  Ctrl-x o.
Anyway i always prefaired using Ctrl-x Ctrl-f, this let you circle between files, using simple, text based file explorer. Previous file is in bacground. You can combine both.